# Intercept touches on obscured views but not child views

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently working on Android Cling like overlay, but with a lot more buttons and a ViewPager.
Currently I can block all touches to elements under the overlay (Which is a transparent page in a view pager) - but it also blocks touches to actual page too - which is no good.

I have no idea how to handle this.
Currently I have

```
public class OverlayPage extends RelativeLayout {



    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        //Draw the semi-transparent background
        canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(248,16,16,16));
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // if it's on a child element return false??
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what you want to block and what not?

Comment: Things under the overlay should be blocked, things in the overlay shouldn't...